# Close align brackets

Tags: matrices, brackets, cases

I was trying to close this bracket:

```
\frac{}{}\theta=2\pi k + \begin{cases}\arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right ) & \text{ if } x> 0 \\ \frac{\pi }{2} & \text{ if } x=0 \\ \arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right )+\pi & \text{ if } x< 0 \end{cases}\
```

(I don't know how to write Latex in here, go to https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{}{}\theta=2\pi k + 
\begin{cases}\arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right ) & \text{ if } x> 0 \\
\frac{\pi }{2} & \text{ if } x=0 \\
\arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right )+\pi & \text{ if } x< 0 \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried using `Bmatrix` intead of `cases` but now the elements aren't aligned:

```
\frac{}{}\theta=2\pi k + \begin{Bmatrix}\arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right ) & \text{ if } x> 0 \\ \frac{\pi }{2} & \text{ if } x=0 \\ \arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right )+\pi & \text{ if } x< 0 \end{Bmatrix}
```

Comment: please always post complete documents not just fragments. What is the intention  of`\frac{}{}` a fraction with no values?

Comment: I added your example. What  do you want to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `alignedat`. The only slight complication is that a thin space would be added in front of “arctan”, but it's easy to remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\theta=2\pi k +
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\! \arctan \frac{n}{x}      &\qquad& \text{if $x>0$} \\
&   \frac{\pi}{2}            &      & \text{if $x=0$} \\
&\! \arctan \frac{n}{x} +\pi &      & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{alignedat}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd go with `cases` and not add the closing brace.

Comment: Upvoted, mainly for the last sentence.

Answer (score 5):

I works if you use the `Bmatrix*` environment from `mathtools`, which takes an optional argument for the alignment (the same in each column):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

        \[ \frac{}{}\theta=2\pi k + \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]\arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right ) & \text{ if } x> 0 \\ \frac{\pi }{2} & \text{ if } x=0 \\ \arctan\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right )+\pi & \text{ if } x< 0 \end{Bmatrix*} \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]